# Tkinter TkinterHtml not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl

I am trying to make a application which automatically installs pypi packages parsed the user selected from websites using `urlopen`. I managed to get the html, decoded and fed it to the TkinterHtml widget. However, it will crash down the python interpreter with an `APPCRASH`. So I replaced the retrieved url to a simpler html text.However, this time it wont render the image onto the widget(non image tags work fine like p). I have tried to read the documentation for the tcl version, but I was unable to apply it to python.

I installed tkinterhtml from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tkinterhtml/).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

from tkinterhtml import TkinterHtml

root = tk.Tk()

html = TkinterHtml(root, fontscale=0.8)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=html.yview)
hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=html.xview)
html.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
html.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)



#html.tag("configure", "selection", "-background", "black")

html.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#data = urlopen("http://www.wikipedia.org").read().decode()
#html.parse(data)
html.parse("""
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>First para</p>
    <ul>
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Google_App_Engine_Logo.png"></img>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
""")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function that retrieves the image and creates a Tk object. This seemed to work for me,

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

# needed to hold references
images = {}

def test(url):
    fp = urlopen(url)
    data = fp.read()
    fp.close()

    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    images[url] = photo
    return photo

root = tk.Tk()

# define imagecmd callback imagecmd=test in order to handle the images
html = TkinterHtml(root, fontscale=0.8, imagecmd=test)
```

[tkhtml documentation](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/tkhtml.html) (TkInterHtml is a wrapper for tkhtml3) states that

> As well as for replacing entire document nodes (i.e. ), images
>   are used in several other contexts in CSS formatted documents, for
>   example as list markers or backgrounds. If the -imagecmd option is not
>   set to an empty string (the default), then each time an image URI is
>   encountered in the document, it is appended to the -imagecmd script
>   and the resulting list evaluated.
>
> The command should return either an empty string, the name of a Tk
>   image, or a list of exactly two elements, the name of a Tk image and a
>   script. If the result is an empty string, then no image can be
>   displayed. If the result is a Tk image name, then the image is
>   displayed in the widget. When the image is no longer required, it is
>   deleted. If the result of the command is a list containing a Tk image
>   name and a script, then instead of deleting the image when it is no
>   longer required, the script is evaluated.

Comment: If the user was to press a hyperlink within the webpage, how can I retrieve the url and parse all the referred images? Is there a callback for this?

Comment: Also, how to use this? do you call the test function? Or do you just parse(urlopen("http://wikipedia.org").read().decode())?

Comment: @user3167683 My guess is that TkInterHtml is suitable only for rendering a webpage, not for user interaction.